# Detecting with code if your iPhone app is live vs test

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I was wondering if there was a way within an app code to determine if the app is real (in the iTunes store) versus test? The reason is that I have every part of in app purchase resolved. However when verifying the receipt you must send it to either https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt if live or https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt if just a test.

Currently I switch the setting prior to submission but I know such an approach can easily fail with a sandbox version being submitted by accident. I would like the code to determine which URL to use.

Comment: Interesting note: We intentionally verified a sandbox receipt against the live verify URL to see what would happen. It verified the sandbox receipt. Did not expect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have it set using some #ifdefs and the different build configurations Xcode can create (i.e. debug vs. release vs. distribution).

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `#define APP_STORE`, or something like that, and check with `#ifdef`. Then, in your build script to build your app store submission from scratch (you do have a one-step build script, [right](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000023.html)?), just have it automatically define `APP_STORE`, and you'll never forget.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into using a one-step build script.